# find something to

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It was found that her blood contained poison.
>
> (1) Her blood was found to contain poison.
>
> (2) Her blood was found containing poison.
>
> (3) They found her blood to contain poison.
>
> (4) They found her blood containing poison.

Are these all grammatical?
If they are, what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 & #3 are generally equivalent in terms of outcome, as are #2 & #4.

#1 emphasizes that poison was found in her blood.

#2 expresses that when her blood was found, it contained poison.

But, #2 can be interpreted the same as #1 depending on context and the listener.

Comment: What do you think  #2 " Her blood was found and it contained poison."  and #4 "They found her blood which contained poison." ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Don't you feel that there is a different nuance between #2 and #4. I've got what you said about #2, what about #4? Can 'containing poison' be used adjectivally to explain what kind of blood?

Comment: Yes, within a specific context, #4 could mean they found the container of her blood which contained poison, as opposed to another container that did not.